# Link an array to another using properties

Tags: c#, arrays, properties

Right now I have something like this:

```
int num1 = 1;
int num2 = 1;

public int Num1
{
    get { return num1; }
    set 
    {
        if(num1 != value)
        {
            num1 = value;
            num2 = value;
            // other stuf
        }
    }
}
```

This happens in a game where i have some points and when the points change i want another number to change. But my problem is that the number of this kind of pairs depends on the number of the players. Can i do something like this where num1 and num2 are arrays with the lenght equal to the number of players? What i want to happen is when num1[i] changes, num2[i] changes as well. On similar questions some people said that properties and arrays shouldn't be combined. If that is true, how else can i accomplish something like this?

**EDIT:**

Sorry, i tought that i should simplify the question, what actually happens is this:

I am using an MVCVM architecture, and i have a NumberViewModel class that looks something like this:

```
class NumberViewModel
{
    public NumberView view = null;
    int number = 0;
    public int Number
    {
        get { return number; }
        set
        {
            if(number != value)
            {
                number = value;
                view.ChangeNumber(number);
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

what the NumberView class does is change a number on screen to the number specified in the NumberViewModel class, so when Number changes, the number on screen also changes

Then i have a PlayerScoreManagerViewModel that looks like this:

```
PlayerScoreManagerViewModel
{
    int player1Score = 0;
    NumberViewModel player1NumberViewModel;

    public int Player1Score
    {
        get { return player1Score; }
        set
        {
            if(player1Score != value)
            {
                player1Score = value;
                player1NumberViewMode.Number = player1Score;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So when the Player1Score changes, the value in the NumberViewModel changes, and this forces NumberView to change the score on screen. I use the NumberViewModel and NumberView in a lot of places so i made it generic.

Comment: What's the point in having two identical values/arrays?  Just use one.  If it's never any different, there's never a purpose to having two.

Comment: Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Comment: Try stepping back and looking at what problem you are trying to solve.  You have to show an attempt which you have... so give us a little more info about what you are trying to do.

Comment: I included the language name because I don't know what other languages have properties and if they do I don't know if they behave the same.